# How does one create a ~/tmp that cleans up automatically on boot and/or on Cron?

Tags: tmp

This is to keep temporary files I create and forget to delete from polluting my file system.  Presumably the target directory could be named anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the standard `/tmp` directory?

Either directly or via a symbolic link from your home directory.

```
ln -s /tmp ~
```

The symbolic link `~/tmp` will behave like a directory and its content will be deleted at [re]boot.

Comment: I've heard/read best practice is avoid doing `home` business in `/`.  Symbolic link partially alleviates this concern...

Comment: Where did you hear that @Zach_is_my_name?

Comment: I cannot implicate any specific agents or parties at this time.

Comment: It is good rule of thumb, that you should not tamper with directories outside your home directory unless you know what you are doing. But `/tmp` is an exception. It is a  directory for temporary files, that you can use manually, or via application programs. Many programs are using `/tmp` for temporary files.

Comment: If you're worried about conflicting with names other users may have given to files in `/tmp`, use `mktemp`

Comment: I'm pretty much sold.  Supposing that I can create as many sym links as I want to /tmp for convenience? That should cover the original question and case.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create more than one sym link pointing to `/tmp`, as many as you wish.

Comment: Is it safe to link /tmp to ~ like that? Surely it is better to `ln -s /tmp ~/somedir`

Comment: The only difference will be the location of the link. Please tell us how it would be safer to locate it in a subdirectory. - But I use another method to 'houseclean' my home directory: I check the new files with `newfiles n` where `newfiles` is a script and  `n` is the number of days back to be checked for `mtime`.